# abrt - use event to copy/move coredump to custom location

Tags: c++, redhat, crash-reports, coredump

I cannot seem to find a way to configure my abrt event to copy the coredump to a custom location. The reason I want to do this is to prevent abrt from pruning my coredumps if the crash directory exceeds `MaxCrashReportsSize`. With the prerequisite that I have no control over how abrt is configured I would like to export the coredump to a support directory as soon as it is created.

```
EVENT=post-create pkg_name=raptorio analyzer=CCpp
    test -f coredump && { mkdir -p /opt/raptorio/cores; cp -f coredump /opt/raptorio/cores/$(basename `cat executable`).core; }
```

This event will save one coredump for each C/C++ binary from my raptorio RPM package. When my program crashes abrt prints the following errors in the syslog:

```
Aug 30 08:28:41 abrtd: mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/raptorio/cores': Permission denied
Aug 30 08:28:41 abrtd: cp: cannot create regular file `/opt/raptorio/cores/raptord.core': No such file or directory
Aug 30 08:28:41 abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-08-30-08:28:10-31213' exited with 1
```

I see that the abrt event runs as `root:root` but it is jailed somehow, possibly due to SELinux? I am using abrt 2.0.8 on centos 6.

Answer (score 0):

/opt is not the right place to keep transient files.  cores should go in /var/raptorio/cores, perhaps.   See the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/)

Assuming your program runs as user 'nobody', make sure 'nobody' has write permissions on that directory, and you should be all set.

Comment: Appreciate the link regarding crash location. The program runs as root (intentionally) but the event still fails to create the directory. When I log the user and group in the event I get `root:root`. Which has write access to /opt.

Comment: @Critikullx - Because /opt is expected to contain programs and libraries, it would not be unexpected that something in SELinux is saying it's a no-no to write a binary file there, as that would be the first step to tricking someone into running an unfriendly executable.  Even if you could defeat that limitation, it would risk opening a security hole.